# Constraint Layout Autoconnect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-3.0

I am following the google codelabs example from here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#7

[image]

As per codelabs, the constraint must be created between textview and plaintextview but there is no any constraint being created as such.

```
constraint-layout version: 1.0.2
android studio version: 3.0 Canary 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Autoconnect only works for parent layout, not other views.
Android Developers site says:
"When turned on, it [autoconnect] automatically creates two or more constraints for each view as you add them to the layout, but only when appropriate to constrain the view to the parent layout. Autoconnect does not create constraints to other views in the layout."